# When I use the change function on ajax, my previous data is not disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

All of my data is posting correctly and my drop box is working. However, when I make different selections I would like the previous data to go away and only the new selection be viewable

Here is my javascript:

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://107.170.75.124/courts/courts.json',
method: 'post'
})
.done (function(data){
   data.forEach(function(item){
    console.log (item.county_name);
      $ ('select').append('<option value="' +  item.county_name + '">' + 
item.county_name + '</option>');    

 });

$('select').on('change', function(item){
var answer = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
    url:'http://107.170.75.124/courts/courts.json',
    method: 'post'
})
.done(function(item){
    data.forEach(function(item){
        if (item.county_name === answer){
           console.log (item.court_name);
              $ ('p').append (item.court_name + '</br>');
              $ ('p').append (item.address + '</br>');
              $ ('p').append (item.phone+ '</br>');



        }
    })
 })
});
});
```

Comment: you always `.append` - nowhere do you clear existing conent

Answer (score 0):

`.append` just adds elements, it doesn't replace them. If you want to replace you need to use `target.html(newStuff)` or `target.replaceWith(newStuff)`

```
data.forEach(function(item){
   var html = '';
   if (item.county_name === answer){
        console.log (item.court_name);
        html += item.court_name + '</br>';
        html += item.address + '</br>';
        html += item.phone+ '</br>';
    }
    $('p').html(html);
})
```

Might be better/more clear if you `filter` the item you want and then `map`

```
var html = data.filter(function(item){
    return item.county_name === answer;
}).map(function(item) {
    return [item.court_name, item.address, item.phone].join('<br />');
});
$('p').html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the `.append` with `.html` to overwrite the data.

Also I recommend you to use `Array.prototype.filter()`. This method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. In this case the same country name.

Also you can replace the  `item.court_name + '</br>' + item.address + '</br>' + item.phone + '</br>';` this expression with `Array.prototype.join()`. This method joins all elements of an array (or an array-like object) into a string.

Like this:

```
var array = [item.court_name, item.address, item.phone];
array.join('<br />');
```

Or just: `[item.court_name, item.address, item.phone].join('<br />');`

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://107.170.75.124/courts/courts.json',
    method: 'post'
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(item) {
      //console.log(item.county_name);
      $('select').append('<option value="' + item.county_name + '">' +
        item.county_name + '</option>');
    });

    $('select').on('change', function(item) {
      var answer = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://107.170.75.124/courts/courts.json',
          method: 'post'
        })
        .done(function(item) {
          var html = data.filter(function(item) {
            return item.county_name === answer;
          }).map(function(item) {
            console.log(item.court_name);
            return [item.court_name, item.address, item.phone].join('<br />');
          });
          $('p').html(html);
        });
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<p></p>
```